# Php Include not working correctly

Tags: php, html, css

Right basically, I have a php include statement in my html document. The include is working as such, it is pulling in the file and displaying it. The include file is basically my navbar, with links. What is happening is that all the other content within the index file is being turned into a hyper link, all pointing to the last item within the ul/li.

Here is my include statement:

```
php include ("/var/www/elements/navbar.html"); ?>
```

Here is my navbar.html file:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.upndown.co/home">Home</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.upndown.co/about">About</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.upndown.co/blog">Blog</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.upndown.co/hardware">Hardware</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.upndown.co/contact">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post the content of `navbar.html`?

Comment: Are you missing the opening <? in your <$php ...?

Comment: Sounds like your missing a closing tag on a link somewhere.

Comment: none of your `<a>` tags have closing tag. maybe you should implement them first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing closing tags on your links

add `</a>`

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.upndown.co/home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.upndown.co/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.upndown.co/blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.upndown.co/hardware">Hardware</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.upndown.co/contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: but the browser is closing the last tag by the end of the page so the whole page is a link to `http://www.upndown.co/contact`.
He got to close each `<a>` tag in the right place